# Is there a simple way to swap 0 and 1 in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, indexing

I have a task where I need to swap the index values within an array.

This is the code that I have written. I am kinda new to js, so it may be a bit off.

```
function swap(arr){
for(let i = 0; i = arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i] == 0){
    return arr[i] + 1
  }
  if (arr[i]== 1){
     return arr[i] - 1
  } 
  }else{
     return "only accepts 0 and 1"
  }
}
console.log(swap[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]])
```

the `console.log` should return `[[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,0,1]]`

Comment: what are you trying to do? You are having function parameter as 1d array and you are passing 2d array

Comment: i have updated my answer, it is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usin array.map() you can solve this problem.
This can be the possible solution:

```
const x = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]];
const result = x.map(el => el.map(item => item === 1 ? 0: 1))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you could make something like this:

const swapArray = [0,1,1].map(index => !index);

Result: swapArray = [true, false, false]

Answer (score 0):

This is brute force, you could do it probably with a map.

```
function swap(arr){
let returnArr = []
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      let returnArr1 = []
      for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        console.log(arr[i][j])
        if(arr[i][j] === 0) returnArr1.push(1)
        else if(arr[i][j] === 1) returnArr1.push(0)  
     }
     returnArr.push(returnArr1)
   }
 return returnArr
}

swap([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]])

[ [ 0, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wanting to do something like this -

```js
function swap(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
     // Here we are just comparing arr[i][j]
     //        - if it is 1, make it 0
     //        - if it is 0, make it 1
      arr[i][j] = (arr[i][j] ? 0 : 1);
    }
  }
  // return the modified array
  return arr;
}
let arr = [
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0]
]
console.log(swap(arr))
```

You could also use a short-hand syntax as follows -

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0]
];

// swapping 0s to 1 and 1s to 0
// The map will take each inner array and each element of that array and modify according to given condition
const swapped_arr = arr.map(inner_array => inner_array.map(el => el ? 0 : 1));
console.log(swapped_arr);
```

I have added comments at places to make you understand.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code below, it works.

```js
function swap(arr){
     arr.forEach((item,index)=>{arr[index]=+!item});
     return arr;
}

console.log(swap([1,0,0]));
console.log(swap([1,1,1]));
console.log(swap([1,0,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function swap(arr){
   return arr.map(x => x.map(j => Number(!j)));
}
console.log(swap([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]]));
```